# Governance Contract too large for Test Net Deployment

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts, hardhat-deploy, goerli, governance

I am trying to deploy this governance contract, created using OpenZeppelin Template and it gives me the ERROR:
`Warning: Contract code size is 29977 bytes and exceeds 24576 bytes (a limit introduced in Spurious Dragon). This contract may not be deployable on Mainnet. Consider enabling the optimizer (with a low "runs" value!), turning off revert strings, or using libraries.`

How can a contract made by OpenZeppelin be oversized?
Am I doing something wrong ? Any Tips on how to make this contract deployable/smaller?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/Governor.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorSettings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorCountingSimple.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorVotes.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorVotesQuorumFraction.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorTimelockControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";

contract GovernanceProtocol is
    GovernorVotes,
    GovernorVotesQuorumFraction,
    GovernorTimelockControl,
    GovernorSettings,
    GovernorCountingSimple,
    AccessControl
{
    constructor(
        IVotes _token,
        TimelockController _timelock,
        uint256 _quorumPercentage,
        uint256 _votingPeriod,
        uint256 _votingDelay
    )
        Governor("GovernanceProtocol")
        GovernorSettings(
            _votingDelay, /* 1 block */ // votind delay
            _votingPeriod, // 45818, /* 1 week */ // voting period
            0 // proposal threshold
        )
        GovernorVotes(_token)
        GovernorVotesQuorumFraction(_quorumPercentage)
        GovernorTimelockControl(_timelock)
    {}

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity

    function votingDelay()
        public
        view
        override(IGovernor, GovernorSettings)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.votingDelay();
    }

    function votingPeriod()
        public
        view
        override(IGovernor, GovernorSettings)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.votingPeriod();
    }

    function quorum(uint256 blockNumber)
        public
        view
        override(IGovernor, GovernorVotesQuorumFraction)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.quorum(blockNumber);
    }

    function state(uint256 proposalId)
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
        returns (ProposalState)
    {
        return super.state(proposalId);
    }

    function proposalThreshold()
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorSettings)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.proposalThreshold();
    }

    function _execute(
        uint256 proposalId,
        address[] memory targets,
        uint256[] memory values,
        bytes[] memory calldatas,
        bytes32 descriptionHash
    ) internal override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl) {
        super._execute(proposalId, targets, values, calldatas, descriptionHash);
    }

    function _cancel(
        address[] memory targets,
        uint256[] memory values,
        bytes[] memory calldatas,
        bytes32 descriptionHash
    ) internal override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl) returns (uint256) {
        return super._cancel(targets, values, calldatas, descriptionHash);
    }

    function _executor()
        internal
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
        returns (address)
    {
        return super._executor();
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl, AccessControl)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile this on remix without any error.
In the 'Solidity Compiler' tab on the left, select 'Advanced Configurations' and enable the optimization with a 200 value.

That should work!

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: And what was the size of the contract under that compilation?
I am trying to deploy it on a Test Net, so the size matters.

Comment: Gas was 4544643 and transaction cost was 3951863 on Remix London vm. You should be able to deploy it. Mark my answer as valid is it helped you so other people find it more easily